# why does numpy slicing seem slower than plain for loops and the array module

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The code i'm writing calculates the sum of divisors of all numbers up to a specified limit. I tried writing it in three ways, two using numpy and one using the array module.

```
N = 10**5
def func2(N,a):
for f in range(2, N//2+1):
    for i in range(f*2, N+1, f):
        a[i] += f
def func3(N,sod):
    for div in range(2,N//2 +1):
        sod[2*div::div]+=div
```

the timing results (using timeit) are:

```
%timeit func2(N,sod)
%timeit func3(N,a)

1 loop, best of 3: 801 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 703 ms per loop
```

And the results really go against my intuition, I would expect that the version with only one for loop would be faster then the version with two for loops and wouldn't expect there to be such a big difference between numpy and the array module. So, what am I missing?

Comment: Get the arrays out of the func definitions and measure again.

Comment: Something wrong with your measurement (or the interpretation of the results). I just ran the functions with `%timeit` in IPython and got 500ms, 150ms, and 300ms. So `func2` is clearly fastest.

Comment: Why are you using `cProfile` instead of `timeit`? As [the big box right at the top of the `cProfile` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) says, "The profiler modules are designed to provide an execution profile for a given program, not for benchmarking purposes (for that, there is timeit for reasonably accurate results). This particularly applies to benchmarking Python code against C code:" Granted, the error is _usually_ going to go in the opposite direction from what you're seeing, but the more important point is that these aren't useful benchmarks in the first place.

Comment: Also… you've apparently presented the results out of order, and then misinterpreted as a result. The slow one in the middle isn't `func2`, the `numpy` slicing version, it's `func1`, the double-loop-over-`numpy` version.

Comment: @kazemakase even with timeit i'm still getting the same results (edited the question).

Comment: Linux or Windows? It looks like you're making a 32-bit `array.array` and a 64-bit NumPy array.

Comment: Linux @user2357112

Comment: You're not getting quite the _same_ results. They are still surprising, but it's no longer true (despite what your text says) that the one-loop numpy version is slower than the two-loop numpy version, or that there's "such a big difference" between numpy and array (it's now around 43% instead of 131%).

Comment: For slices that pick out very few values, like `a[3000::1500]` when `a` has 10000 elements, I could easily believe that iterating only 5 times is faster than operating on an extended slice. I don't think that's relevant here, that most of your slices will be pretty big, but reading this on a phone screen while holding it out of the rain… maybe someone else can check that.

Comment: @abarnert did a small check and you are correct, when slicing picks only a really small subset of values iterating is indeed faster

Comment: OK, and is your test spending a lot of time on really small slices? When I get a chance later, I can do my own tests and, if this turns out to be relevant, I can explain what's going on and put it in an answer, but if you can rule that out beforehand, you'll save me some time…

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you're using `cProfile` for benchmarking. As the big box at the top of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) says:

> The profiler modules are designed to provide an execution profile for a given program, not for benchmarking purposes (for that, there is timeit for reasonably accurate results). This particularly applies to benchmarking Python code against C code…

---

The second problem is that you seem to have read your results out of order:

```
1    0.359    0.359    0.359    0.359 toiprof.py:13(func3)
1    1.568    1.568    1.569    1.569 toiprof.py:4(func1)
1    0.679    0.679    0.679    0.679 toiprof.py:9(func2)
```

Yes, the second output is much slower than the first and third—but the second output is `func1`, not `func2`. So numpy slicing (`func2`) is actually much faster than looping over numpy (`func1`), not slower.

---

The third problem is that you're creating the arrays inside the loop that you're timing, and this is actually a non-trivial cost. Numpy is slower at creating large arrays than `array`, but that's rarely an issue in real life for the simple reason that you're usually doing a whole lot more work per array than just creating it. I'm not sure if that's relevant in this case or not, but it could be, and it's a lot easier to just not do that than to try to measure and prove that doing that didn't really hurt anything.

---

When I change the arrays to be parameters, use `%timeit` in iPython, and interpret the results in the right order, I see `func2` as a little faster than `func3` and much faster than `func1`. Since that agrees with the results that kazemakase posted in a comment, it's pretty likely that at least one of three problems above is responsible for your different numbers.

In other words, numpy slicing seems to be slower because you measured it wrong, not because of anything to do with numpy or array or loops.

Comment: Now I am doing exactly what you did  - preallocating the arrays and still the version with the array module is faster for me by about 100 ms.

Answer (score 0):

The reason two for loops are faster than slicing is that when slicing returns only a small subset of the array iterating is faster.

```
def npslice(arr,num):
    arr[num::num]+=num
def arriter(arr,num,l):
    for a in range(num,l,num):
        arr[a]+=num
```

and the timing*:

```
%timeit -n1 -r1 npslice(sod2,50000)
%timeit -n1 -r1 arriter(sod2,50000,N+1)

1 loop, best of 1: 82 µs per loop
1 loop, best of 1: 65.1 µs per loop
```

So for most of the way (inside the outer for loop) the (inner) for loop is a bit faster than slicing using numpy.

the "-n1 -r1" options are set because the python interpeter optimizes the slicing operation when it is preformed more than once so the timeit function throws this warning when it is not set -

```
The slowest run took 5.07 times longer than the fastest. This could 
mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
```